# Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `rrrr` supplied to `sportsMockUpStandard`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, mocha.js

https://gist.github.com/js08/dfeab2df8b68240297eb

- i am trying to write a test case for a jsx file
- in this I am able to pass proptypes...
- but not where I have passed proptypes propely...
- i am getting an error when i run my test case..
- providing my error, test case and code below...
- Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `rrrr` supplied to `sportsMockUpStandard`.
- not sure how to make it work ..
- its happing at this function dispatch..
- can you tell me how should i need to put it in my test case

  ```
  **error** 
  ---
   1) shallow renderer tests for sports-template-standard  should render correctly:
  ```

  Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `rrrr` supplied to `sportsMockUpStandard`.

  ```
  test cases
  ---


  describe('shallow renderer tests for sports-template-standard ', function() {
      let shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
      console.log("shallowRenderer" + JSON.stringify(shallowRenderer));

      it('should render correctly', () => {

         // var rightPanel ="some string";
          var layout ="some string";        
           var hasSidebar = function(){
              done();
      }
          console.log("here1");
        //  this.props.layout.rightPanel.exists = 'some value';

      shallowRenderer.render(<sportsMockUpStandard

          sidebar= {[{hasSidebar},{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}]}
  ```

  />);

  ```
             // shallowRenderer.render(<sportsMockUpStandard

              //layout= {{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}}  />); 

           console.log("here2");

      });

  });
  ```

  ```

Comment: why did you change the error about 'sidebar' in your question to 'rrrr'? It makes the answer given before the change appear as if it's not about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off by looking at the warning you get:

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop rrrr supplied to
>   sportsMockUpStandard.

This tells you that something is wrong with the `rrrr` property that you supply to `sportsMockUpStandard`. So let's take a look at that. In `sportsMockUpStandard` you have

```
rrrr: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.func,
    React.PropTypes.object
]),
```

so it is expecting either a function or an object. However, in the test case you create a `sportsMockUpStandard` element with `rrrr` being an array:

```
rrrr= {[{rrrr},{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}]}
```

Just add `React.PropTypes.array`, and you should be good.

*Update:*
I really recommend starting by understanding how Mocha works. Your current test doesn't check anything, but just finishes when done() is executed. When you use chai the normal setup is something like this:

```
describe('the thing you want to test', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    /* Run some code */
    expect(/*something*/).to.equal(/*something*/);
  })
})
```

So let's say you have a function:

```
function addOne(number){
  return number + 1;
}
```

Then your test will look like this:

```
describe('addOne', () => {
  it('should take a number and increment it by one', () => {
    var number = 5;
    var newNumber = addOne(number);
    expect(newNumber).to.equal(6); // Success!!
  })
})
```

Once you have the basics down, testing React components should be a lot easier.

Comment: @dannyjoile I tried with several syntax in my test case but its not working...can you update my test case for function....pls

Comment: After looking at your code again, I see that you actually need sidebar to be either a function or an object. Why are you supplying it as an array? Simply change `sidebar= {[{hasSidebar},{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}]}` to `sidebar={hasSidebar}` or `sidebar={{id: 100, text: 'hello world}}` in the test case depending on what you wish to test.

Comment: And the hasSidebar function in the test case doesn't make sense. It doesn't return anything, and only executes a function `done()` that doesn't exist.